# Triple-Boot Windows 10, Linux Mint and Fedora Scientific - Grub Setup

Tags: windows-10, installation, fedora, grub, linux-mint

I currently have Win 10 and Linux Mint installed and would like to give Fedora Scientific a try. I'll reduce the Windows partition with Windows' tool. My question is regarding the installation of Grub. The current setup is as follows:

```
~$ grub-install --version
grub-install.real (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9

~$ lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─sda1           8:1    0  1000M  0 part  
├─sda2           8:2    0   260M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda3           8:3    0   128M  0 part  
├─sda4           8:4    0 258,7G  0 part  
├─sda5           8:5    0  13,8G  0 part  
├─sda6           8:6    0  46,6G  0 part  /
├─sda7           8:7    0  14,9G  0 part  
│ └─cryptswap1 252:0    0  14,9G  0 crypt [SWAP]
└─sda8           8:8    0 141,7G  0 part  /home
```

Should I install Grub again when installing Fedora or should I rather update grub after installing? Anything I need to consider when installing grub with Fedora (I have only used Debian based distros so far)?

Comment: This seems like an obvious place where virtualization would be appropriate.  You could use Hyper-V, VirtualBox, VMWare, etc to load a "guest" OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora's installer has grub included, so it will install/re-install itself and then automatically run `os-prober` which unless you have some odd issue/deployment OR some rare edge case, will pick up and create entries for Windows 10 and Linux Mint.

Comment: Just to make sure. Install grub on sda2 again?

Comment: NO fedora's installer will silently handle that as part of the built-in post-install scripts.